# How to get any FDR-persistent Id (except IMEI )?

Tags: android, udid

I'm generating UDID for the device based on IMEI. now I need any other id that survives factory data reset. Any solution?

Comment: u can check details here .https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#resettability-persistence